# <? include_once in a div?

Tags: php, html, css

I just need to place a `<? include_once ("SOMETHING.PHP"); ?>` inside a div. Every time I put the include_once in the div, the SOMETHING.PHP won't show inside the div!! it will end up outside of the div!

here is my div CSS code:

```
#bcg {
    -moz-border-radius:10px;  /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius:10px; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
    border-radius:10px; /* regular */
    border-color:#000;
    opacity:0.5; /* Transparent Background 50% */
    background-image:url(imgs/gray_jean.png);
    height:500px;
    width:450px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

and this is how I put the include_once inside the div:

```
<div id="bcg"><?php include_once("something.php");?></div>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong!! any help would be appreciated.

This is `something.php`

```
<?php

$username="";
$password="";
$database="";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database"); 

$query="SELECT * FROM pages"; 

$result=mysql_query($query); 
$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

?>

<?php

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"pagebody");
?>
<table width="350" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="76">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: And what is in `something.php`?

Comment: Can you post the PHP you're trying to include?

Comment: Are you calling `include_once("something.php");` somewhere else, too? If its contents should always be printed at exactly this position, you probably want to call `incldue(...);`.

Comment: Edit your question with the provided contents.

Comment: @Ranon, yes, i am using in other locations as well. so i cant use include(...). Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: Note: The `mysql_` functions are depricated. Please implement `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: @RobB, Someone has already done it for me. sorry and Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Supericy, do you think that would help with my issue?

Comment: Is it outside in the browser or in the generated html code?

Answer (score 1):

Try catching the output from the included script in an output buffer, and then echoing it.

```
<div id="bcg">
    <?php
        ob_start();

        include_once("something.php");

        echo ob_get_clean();
    ?>
</div>
```